# How to add product thumbnails to Checkout?

Tags: 7, media, ubercart

I am wondering if anyone can help me figure this out. Using Drupal 7, and Ubercart 3x.

I'm trying to add the product thumbnails to the checkout pane as they show up in the "View Cart" pane. The table seems largely the same minus the fact that on the checkout page itself, there are no thumbnails of the products. I'm okay with PHP and poking around haven't been able to find how I could add this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the theme function uc_cart_review_table to accomplish this.

```
function YOUR_THEME_uc_cart_review_table($variables) {
  $items = $variables['items'];
  $show_subtotal = $variables['show_subtotal'];

  $subtotal = 0;

  // Set up table header.
  $header = array(
    array('data' => theme('uc_qty_label'), 'class' => array('qty')),
    array('data' => t('Products'), 'class' => array('products'), 'colspan' => 2),
    array('data' => t('Price'), 'class' => array('price')),
  );

  // Set up table rows.
  $display_items = uc_order_product_view_multiple($items);
  if (!empty($display_items['uc_order_product'])) {
    foreach (element_children($display_items['uc_order_product']) as $key) {
      $display_item = $display_items['uc_order_product'][$key];
      $image = uc_product_get_picture($display_item['#entity']->nid, 'uc_cart');

      $subtotal += $display_item['total']['#price'];
      $rows[] = array(
        array('data' => $display_item['qty'], 'class' => array('qty')),
        array('data' => $image, 'class' => array('image')),
        array('data' => $display_item['product'], 'class' => array('products')),
        array('data' => $display_item['total'], 'class' => array('price')),
      );
    }
  }

  // Add the subtotal as the final row.
  if ($show_subtotal) {
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        // One cell
        array(
          'data' => array(
            '#theme' => 'uc_price',
            '#prefix' => '<span id="subtotal-title">' . t('Subtotal:') . '</span> ',
            '#price' => $subtotal,
          ),
          // Cell attributes
          'colspan' => 4,
          'class' => array('subtotal'),
        ),
      ),
      // Row attributes
      'class' => array('subtotal'),
    );
  }

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('cart-review')), 'sticky' => FALSE));
}
```

With the code `$image = uc_product_get_picture($display_item['#entity']->nid, 'uc_cart');` you can read out the product image and add it to the table.